# MySQL query with total percentage by id

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
"Order1", "Product1", "3"
"Order1", "product2", "5"
"Order2", "product1", "2"
```

And so on, and I want a query that outputs something like this:

```
"Order1", "Product1", "3/8"
"Order1", "product2", "5/8"
"Order2", "product1", "2/n"
```

The 8 is the sum of the total quantity of the products on each order.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You'll really need to add column names here if anyone is to be able to coach you through how to make a query for this.

Comment: in addition to @tadman, also include what you have tried so far, we are not here to write your code

Comment: I am sorry about it, I am not very good at asking questions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be work for you:

```
SELECT s.ordernr
      ,p.product
      ,CONCAT(p.quantity, '/', sum(s.quantity) AS percentage
FROM yourtable s
LEFT JOIN yourtable p ON p.orderid = s.oerderid
GROUP BY s.ordernr
ORDER BY s.ordernr;
```

Comment: I found myself the answer, but it is pretty similar to yours:

SELECT table1.order_no, table1.product, (quantity/(select sum(quantity) from table2 where order_no = table1.order_no)) AS percent FROM `table_1_original` AS table1 ORDER BY order_no, product ASC";